# get an value of key that is in array object

Tags: php

I have a problem with getting value of an key that is in an array. I'm not very deep into php and got lost at some point.

My result :

```
stdClass Object(
  [code] => 200
  [status] => success
  [message] => 
  [data] => Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object(
      [vps] => smtp2 - 687
      [hardbounce_desc] => host gmail - smtp - in .l.google.com [64.233 .164 .26] said: 550 - 5.1 .1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist.Please
                  try 550 - 5.1 .1 double - checking the recipient 's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser x90si7716568ljb.275 - gsmtp (in reply to RCPT TO command) 
      [hardbounce_time] => 2018-03-08 09:50:00 [account] => my.smtp [injected_time] => 2018-03-08 09:49:59 [message_id] => 61375aa0f937a2fcd8.04158271_65b85dbf1016581ba7710e6f5a799d28@api.emaillabs.net.pl 
      [ok_desc] => 
      [ok_time] => 
      [open_desc] => 
      [open_time] => 
      [postfix_id] => Array ( 
        [0] => 3zxkjM4tJqz8rgnS 
        [1] => 3zxkjM5xSRz1Y5j6 
      ) 
      [tracking] => Array ( ) 
      [tags] => Array ( ) 
      [to] => mymail@mail.com [uid] => 56aa510e20123485c0068bafde397e23 
      [from] => testemail 
      [subject] => bbbbbbb 
      [created_at] => 2018-03-08 09:49:59 
      [updated_at] => 
      [id] => 5aa0f9c0d26d44a191b7cbe5 
    ) 
  ) 
  [req_id] => lbUSoGjS8K 
)
```

What i am trying to do is getting value of `hardbounce_desc` or `ok_desc` like this:

```
if ($json->data['hardbounce_desc'] != null) {
        echo 'hardbounce';
    }
if ($json->data['ok_desc'] != null) {
        echo 'ok';
    }
```

But this is not how it works. My question is how can i check if value of key `harbounce_desc` or `ok_desc` is not null.

Comment: "But this is not how it works" -> why not? This looks fine for checking if it is null, if it's also possible that the key doesn't exist at all, you could use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: One way to solve your problem is doing some `var_dump()` to see what you get and how you get it ! Eg. `var_dump(--your obj--)`, then `var_dump(--your obj['data']--)` and so on untill you find where is the value you want :) When you work with array / obj it's not hard to debug, you only need to take some time to understand where you are and how to get the data you want !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$data` is an array that contains one object. Try this :

```
if (isset($json->data[0]) && isset($json->data[0]->hardbounce_desc)) {
    echo 'hardbounce';
}
if (isset($json->data[0]) && isset($json->data[0]->ok_desc)) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

With full check :

```
if (is_object($json) && 
    isset($json->data) &&  is_array($json->data) && 
    !empty($json->data) && 
    is_object($json->data[0]) && 
    isset($json->data[0]->hardbounce_desc)) 
{
    echo 'hardbounce';
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much. Now i understand ! :) I will mark as anwser when i can after 7 minutes.

Comment: @W.Lukasiewicz You're welcome, you could also test if `$json->data` is an array using `is_array()` and if it is not empty, and if `$json->data[0]` is an object.

Comment: @W.Lukasiewicz I've updated the answer with a "full check" example.

Comment: Thank you @Syscall I will try both examples :)